# There is any configuration for this tools eclipse or wamp or android sdk to connect my mobile phone to wampserver

Tags: android

here is any configuration for this tools eclipse or wamp or android sdk to connect my mobile phone to wampserver?
i look this exemple in this site blow i just copy and paste the code in eclipse but the problem is how i can import and export data from my phone to database and Conversely ?
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you're running a wamp server locally on your computer and you'd like to access that server from your application. The general approach is similar to connecting to any other server, but you'd have to find the right IP-address to connect to. Try this:

First, make sure your server is up and running.

Second, access the server on your computer using one of two addresses:
If you're testing your app on the emulator (AVD), use this: 10.0.2.2, which translates to the localhost-address on your computer.

If you're testing your app on an actual device, you'd have to find your computer's IP-address. On linux, open a terminal and execute the command ifconfig. In windows, I believe it's ipconfig. Use the address listed under wlan0 -> inet addr.

Remember to append the port number your server is running on.

**EDIT**
Example, given port number is 80:

Emulator: 10.0.2.2:80
Device:   192.168.X.X:80